# Как написать обобщённый код для всех специализаций шаблонного класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Есть шаблонный класс `template <int I> Foo` и две его специализации. Как мне что-то определить внутри `Foo`, чтобы это было видно во всех его специализациях? Например:

```
template <int I>
class Foo {
 public:
   enum class Bat
   {
      One = 1,
      Two = 2
   };
};

template <>
class Foo<1> {
   void SomeFunction( Bat bat ); // Bat неопределённо. 
};

template <>
class Foo<2> {
   void SomeFunction( Bat bat );
};
```

Comment: Описать `enum class Bat` и в специализации. Или вынести его в базовый класс и наследовать всеми `Foo`. Так не сойдет?

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за ответ. Сделал как предложил KoVadim, но вопрос, как обобщить код для специализаций не наследуя для меня остался открытым. Мне не понятно, почему, когда дизайнили эту часть С++ не могли сделать возможность писать общий для всех специализай код.

Comment: Потому что это резко ограничило бы возможности специализации. Вот, например, перегрузка функций — как вы напишете общий для всех перегрузок код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое, что могу предложить - вынести в отдельный базовый класс

```
class Base {
    public:
   enum class Bat
   {
      One = 1,
      Two = 2
   };
};

   template <int I>
class Foo: public Base {

};

template <>
class Foo<1>: public Base {
   void SomeFunction( Bat bat );
};

template <>
class Foo<2> : public Base {
   void SomeFunction( Bat bat );
};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал через наследование. Хотя конечно не самое изящное решение.

Comment: есть много других способов. Например, можно через макросы (но тут есть много "программистов", которые их не любят (точнее боятся). Можно, попробовать просто енум поменстить с классами в отдельный namespace. Все сильно зависит от конкретной задачи.